# Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, bluehost

I use VS Code as my editor and am using BlueHost to host a series of domains and websites. I have installed git onto BlueHost and created a repository there. I've cloned that repository locally.

When pushing commits using `git push origin master` on the command line, I am prompted for the password to my BlueHost account, and everything operates as expected. When using the 'Push' menu option from the Source Control tab on VS Code, however, I am not prompted at all and get the error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I read through loads of similarly-posed questions and tried a number of potential solutions, including generating an SSH key on BlueHost and putting that key in my .ssh folder (tried with both public and private keys) and also generating keys using `ssh-keygen` and importing the public key to BlueHost, but haven't made any headway. I'm starting to think this issue may be a corner case with my particular combination of services being used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem appears to be that you’ve generated the SSH key all right, but haven’t told your computer to use it. To verify this, try using `ssh -v user@hostname` (verbose mode), which will show you what keys your computer attempts to present to the remote host.

If that is indeed the issue, it’s simple to fix. You’ll need to add the SSH key to your SSH agent so that your computer knows to try using it.  I don’t know what OS you’re using, but for example, on Mac OS, you’d do `ssh-add path/to/key-file`. GitHub has an excellent set of instructions at https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/ , which you should follow (these instructions should work with any Git remote, not just GitHub). VS Code may have some sort of key management UI in its Git module; I’ve never used it, so I have no idea.

Comment: Note all the “no such file” errors regarding your keys. That suggests to me that your key pairs are broken—perhaps you have only the private key but not the public, or vice versa. Look in your `.ssh` directory: you should have pairs of files named `whatever.pub` (the public key) and `whatever` (the corresponding private one). Do you? • Also, you should consider one of the “pastie” services, or Gist, instead of Google Docs for things like this

Comment: I have the keys I generated, `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, in my `.ssh` directory and have imported the keys both individually and together into BlueHost, I've also done the reverse--generating the keys from BlueHost and uploading them into my `.ssh` directory. Also, you're right--thanks for the note. I'll change the link.

Comment: Couldn't edit the comment. Here's the original comment with the link changed: "Thanks for the suggestions, Marnen! Unfortunately, I'm still dealing with this issue, and there doesn't seem to be any key management UI in VS Code. Here's a link to the read-out from when I enter the 'ssh -v user@hostname' command: https://gist.github.com/nckgrzn/8aa4f8c998e6c97f0fe2a063e41660ec It seems to be using, or trying to use, the right key files, but I am then still prompted for my password (highlighted line), upon which I enter it and am connected. Any other thoughts after seeing this? Thanks in advance,"

Comment: Your private key should not be on the remote host; you’ve now compromised its security. You should generate a new key pair. I would recommend reading a basic overview of SSH key management, since the steps you’ve described taking suggest that you’re trying things without the basic understanding you need. I suspect if you read more, you will figure out the problem (and I’ll keep thinking about it as well, of course).

Comment: Will do. Please let me know if your thinkings yield anything further. I'll edit the post if I come upon anything myself. Thanks again,

Comment: Thanks so much, I was dealing with some weird issues, including never being prompted for the password to my key (everything in Google was trying to turn that off, meanwhile I wasn't seeing it). My `ssh-keygen` must have screwed up and not added the key (I've made plenty of keys before that just worked so I was a little confused). But using `-v` showed it was trying all the defaults and never my actual key. After manually adding it, it now works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your SSH config is all right (in /etc/ssh/sshd_config for debian/ubuntu) :

- Only one auth method activated and others declared (not commented) and set to "no" : PubkeyAuthentication, RSA (if exists) and PasswordAuthentication

  - eventually check if PermitRootLogin or UseLogin is necessary
  - if needed, check if line with authorized_keys is uncommented

Then restart SSHD with the good old /etc/init.d/ssh restart (yes, yes, there are better methods, but this still works and do the right thing :-))